# Windows forms dynamically evenly distribute controls?

Tags: c#, devexpress, flowlayoutpanel

I am making a lot of camera tracking applications. I want to open the selected cameras in a layout. But mostly one camera will be watched. But I also have to do something to watch multiple. I want the screen to be divided into 2 when there are 2 cameras and when there are 3 cameras, the screen will be divided into 4. I couldn't do it with FlowLayoutControl. Because it is necessary to give dimension to the video control that I added. How should I do such a thing. I'm adding a screenshot of the fixed size control insertion part. I did the thing in the image but gave 200x200 dimensions to the controls inside. This is not what I really want to do. I want controls that change dynamically in size according to the number of controls. How do i do this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel. Define two columns and add or remove rows if necessary.

Comment: Is it possible to show full screen since there is only one video control?

Comment: You can set the other columns size to AutoSize. If you do that and there is no control within the second column the control should be displayed 'fullscreen'. Just check in some subroutine if there only is one video control and change the size property of the columns accordingly.